# How do I make get attr_accessor_with_default work with a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to give one of my models an attribute accessor that defaults to an array of eight zeros. This is the first syntax I tried:

```
attr_accessor_with_default:weekly_magnitude_list, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The above didn't do what I expected because all instances of the model end up sharing the same Array object. The blog (http://barelyenough.org/blog/2007/09/things-to-be-suspicious-of-attr_accessor_with_default-with-a-collection/) that clued me into that suggested a different syntax, basically wrapping the default value in a block.

```
attr_accessor_with_default(:weekly_magnitude_list) {[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

That doesn't work (for me, in Rails 3). Any time I call the accessor, I seem to be getting a completely new Array object. That effectively means I can't write to it.

Does anybody know the correct way to do this?

For your pleasure, I've included the output of a simple test demonstrating this:

```
class Container
  attr_accessor_with_default :naive_collection, [0,0]
  attr_accessor_with_default(:block_collection) {[0,0]}
end   
> c = Container.new
=> #<Container:0x7f3610f717a8>
> c.naive_collection[0] = "foo"  
=> "foo"   
> Container.new.naive_collection
=> ["foo", 0]
# expected [0,0]

> c.block_collection[0] = "foo"
=> "foo"
> c.block_collection
=> [0, 0]
# expected ["foo", 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled onto this question while running into the same problem.

For reference, the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/attr_accessor_with_default) specify the block form is dynamically evaluated in the instance scope.  To continue the example, its usefulness is really quite limited, but at least works the way you might expect:

```
class Container
  attr_accessor_with_default(:block_collection) { name.underscore }
end

> c = Container.new(:name => "TestName")
> c.block_collection  # => "test_name"
> c.block_collection = "something else"  # => "something else"
> c.name => "TestName"
```

Here's the really quirky part though...

```
class Container
  attr_accessor_with_default :naive_collection, [0, 0]
end

# This works as expected
> c = Container.new
> c.naive_collection = ["foo", "bar"]  # => ["foo", "bar"]
> Container.new.naive_collection  # => [0, 0]
> c.naive_collection[0] = 0  # => [0, "bar"]
> Container.new.naive_collection  # => [0, 0]

# But this doesn't
> c2 = Container.new
> c2.naive_collection  # => [0, 0]
> c2.naive_collection[0] = "problem!"  # => ["problem!", 0]
> Container.new.naive_collection  # => ["problem!", 0]
```

Digging into the source a bit, I see that attr_accessor_with_default defines an instance method that returns the default value or executes the block.  Which is fine.

It then goes on to execute this within a module_eval:

```
def #{sym}=(value)
  class << self;
    attr_reader :#{sym}
  end

  @#{sym} = value
end
```

Which is just ridiculously convoluted.  I may end up ticketing this as a bug if I can't figure out the motivation for this behavior.

**Update:**

I managed to figure out what was going wrong here.

```
def attr_accessor_with_default(sym, default = Proc.new)
  define_method(sym, block_given? ? default : Proc.new { default })
  module_eval(<<-EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1)
    def #{sym}=(value)
      class << self; attr_accessor :#{sym} end
      @#{sym} = value
    end
  EVAL
end
```

Initially, the default value exists as a proc.
Once you invoke the setter, the getter and setter methods are overwritten by attr_accessor methods and the instance variable is initialized.
The problem is that the default proc in the getter returns the class-level default value.  So when you do something like:

```
> c2.naive_collection[0] = "problem!"  # => ["problem!", 0]
```

you're actually changing the default value for the class.

I think this method should probably be implemented as:

```
class Module
  def attr_accessor_with_default(sym, default = Proc.new)
    module_eval(<<-EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1)
      def #{sym}
        class << self; attr_reader :#{sym} end
        @#{sym} = #{ default.dup }
      end

      def #{sym}=(value)
        class << self; attr_accessor :#{sym} end
        @#{sym} = value
      end
    EVAL
  end
end
```

I'll ticket it and offer up a patch.

**Update again:**
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/6496